# Qual è il significato di "figura" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il barone rampante*, di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Infatti, molta di questa sua orrenda cucina era studiata solo per la **figura**, più che per il piacere di farci gustare insieme a lei cibi dai sapori raccapriccianti. Erano, questi piatti di Battista, delle opere di finissima oraferia animale o vegetale: teste di cavolfiore con orecchie di lepre poste su un colletto di pelo di lepre; o una testa di porco dalla cui bocca usciva, come cacciasse fuori la lingua, un’aragosta rossa, e l’aragosta nelle pinze teneva la lingua del maiale come se glie l’avesse strappata. Poi le lumache: era riuscita a decapitare non so quante lumache, e le teste, quelle teste di 
>   cavallucci molli molli, le aveva infisse, credo con uno stecchino, ognuna su un bignè, e parevano, come vennero in tavola, uno stormo di piccolissimi cigni. E ancor più della vista di quei manicaretti 
>   faceva impressione pensare dello zelante accanimento che certo Battista v’aveva messo a prepararli, immaginare le sue mani sottili mentre smembravano quei corpicini d’animali.

La mia domanda è sul significato del termine "figura" che appare in questo brano. Ho cercato questo vocabolo in parecchi dizionari ma, tra le tante accezioni che appaiono, non so a quale corrisponda l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mio avviso intende che era studiata solo per l'impatto estetico e nient'altro; si usa anche il modo di dire **"fare figura"** (o "fare scena") (vedi http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/figura/):

> 10. Apparenza e, in partic., bella apparenza: *ci sta per f. e non per altro; mettersi un fiore all’occhiello per f.; di figura*, come locuz. agg., di bell’aspetto, che fa bella mostra: *un vestito, un arredamento, un soprammobile, una decorazione di f.; fare figura*, comparire bene, destare ammirazione[...]